# Using linux capabilites to read discontinuous runs of blocks

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, hard-drive

What is the best approach to read a file with a dbms style access pattern; I mean the following:

- I know before hand the offsets of pages that I need to fetch.
- There are long runs of consecutive pages.
- There can be small discontinuities.
- There can be long discontinuities.
- all the offsets are ordered (no back an forth movements).

Example of such offset list: 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1000,1001,1003,1004,1005,1010,1011,1012,31004,31005,31006.

I am a bit confused on which strategy to use in order to get best performances.

- Shall I rely on Linux page manager? how? will looping through the
  offsets and read 1 block at a time ok ?
- Open the file with O_DIRECT and manage my self, ie: alternating long reads and seeks. Shall I disable the readahead in this case ?

Comment: `O_DIRECT` can be very hard to use because you have to manage the alignment yourself.

Comment: You can use the Linux `aio` or the posix `aio` interface, and queue up all your requests. The driver should be able to figure out the best way to complete your reads.

Comment: did you try mmap , to see the performance ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's ultimately the "best", but I would probably `mmap()` the file, then use `madvise()` to try to coerce the system to pre-fault page ranges. Obviously, that would also require a little calculation on your offset list to identify contiguous ranges (ok, it wouldn't actually require it, but that would cut down on `madvise()` calls and gain a little efficiency if there are a lot of such ranges). How far ahead to pre-fault would depend on how much time you spend on each page/range doing whatever calculations you're trying to do, so some testing/tuning would be necessary. You can also use `madvise()` to hint that you no longer need a range after you're done with it, so it might get bumped to the front of the to-be-freed-next list.

Comment: Ok I'll try the mmap, but that means completely relying on the OS to do the right read ahead and buffering. I was hoping that I can do something smarter manually since I can organize my operations. Something like: read(fd,run1,..) lseek() read(fd, run2, ..) lseek etc. But that suggest I disable read ahead and decide myself what is a small discontinuity (that I better read) from a big one (that I should seek).